# LibGdx - Transition between Screens

Tags: screen, libgdx

I'm trying to change the animation between Libgdx Screens. I want to write my custom animation (fade in, fade out, etc). Can someone give me a clue?
I can't seem to find the implementation of the transition in the Libgdx code.

Comment: What's your setup now? Are you using the [`Game`](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.html) and [`Screen`](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) classes?

Comment: Yes. A I have a class that deals with the logic of changing between Screens that implements Game. And 2 other classes that implement Screen(this is where I draw a Stage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented some sliding transitions using Scene2D and the universal tween engine. You can find example code here.

http://www.netthreads.co.uk/2012/02/09/libgdx-scene2d-demo-with-scene-transitions/

Update: This article illustrates the approach I took to implement sliding transitions. There is a link at the bottom which takes you to a set of demos here https://github.com/alistairrutherford/libgdx-demos

There are clear instructions on how to build the demos but you will need to have at least a basic grasp of maven and how to set it up.

Comment: Is this answer this valid as per today [Oct 2014] ? Spent last hours try to install the alistairrutherford/netthreads-libgdx with Maven but never managed to have anything working. Is there a walk-through trough the installation process ?

Comment: And now the link seems to be dead. This is why you should never answer a question with a simple link.

Comment: Seems like it was just a temporary thing. I'm still not changing my vote because [it is still a link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/213556) and you have not addressed the first comment by dawez.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about `Screen`, not `Scene`. After digging through the linked source code, it turns out that `Scene` is just an extension of `Stage`, so isn't related to the concept of a libgdx `Screen`. See [here](https://github.com/alistairrutherford/netthreads-libgdx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/netthreads/libgdx/scene/Scene.java)

Answer (score 20):

Here is what i do:

FadeIn is pretty simple, just add this to your fadein Screens show():

```
stage.getRoot().getColor().a = 0;
stage.getRoot().addAction(fadeIn(0.5f));
```

FadeOut is a little trickier. You dont want to switch screens immediately, so instead of calling game.setScreen(newScreen) create a method in your fadeout Screen like this:

```
public void switchScreen(final Game game, final Screen newScreen){
    stage.getRoot().getColor().a = 1;
    SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction();
    sequenceAction.addAction(fadeOut(0.5f));
    sequenceAction.addAction(run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            game.setScreen(newScreen);
        }
    }));
    stage.getRoot().addAction(sequenceAction);
}
```

Like this, you delay the screen switching for the duration of the fade out.

Comment: I had to make 2 minor changes to this code run for me. `fadeOut(0.5f)` → `Actions.fadeOut(0.5f)`, and `run(new Runnable()` → `Actions.run(new Runnable()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code of my game in transitions animation between screens:
in `MainGame` class:

```
@Override public void setScreen(final Screen screen) {
        if (getScreen() == null)
        {
            createScreenInAction(screen);
            return;
        }
        createScreenOutAction(getScreen(), new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                createScreenInAction(screen);
            }
        });

    }
    private void createScreenOutAction(final Screen screen , Runnable runnable) {
        Actor actor = ((BaseScreenAdapter) screen).getStage().getRoot();
        actor.setOrigin(WIDTH_HALF,HEIGHT_HALF);
        actor.getColor().a = 1;
        SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction();
        sequenceAction.addAction(Actions.parallel(Actions.alpha(0,SCREEN_SWITCH_DURATION) , Actions.scaleTo(1.5f,1.5f , SCREEN_SWITCH_DURATION, Interpolation.exp5)));
        sequenceAction.addAction(Actions.run(runnable));
        actor.addAction(sequenceAction);
    }
    private void createScreenInAction(final Screen screen) {
        StarsGame.super.setScreen(screen);
        Actor actor = ((BaseScreenAdapter) screen).getStage().getRoot();
        actor.setOrigin(WIDTH_HALF,HEIGHT_HALF);
        actor.getColor().a = 0;
        SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction();
        sequenceAction.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(1.5f,1.5f , 0));
        sequenceAction.addAction(Actions.parallel(Actions.alpha(1,SCREEN_SWITCH_DURATION) , Actions.scaleTo(1.0f,1.0f , SCREEN_SWITCH_DURATION , Interpolation.exp5)));
        actor.addAction(sequenceAction);

    }
```

and all my screens extends as `BaseScreenAdapter`:

```
public abstract class BaseScreenAdapter extends ScreenAdapter implements BaseRequest.BaseResponseError{
    protected final AssetsController mAssets;
    protected final MySettings mSettings;
    protected StarsGame mGame;
    protected Stage mStage;
    protected Viewport mViewport;
    protected OrthographicCamera mCamera;
    protected InputMultiplexer multiplexer;
    protected LoadingActor mLoadingActor;
    //==============================================================
    // METHODS
    //==============================================================
    public BaseScreenAdapter(StarsGame game) {
        this.mGame = game;
        mCamera = new OrthographicCamera(/*StarsGame.WIDTH, StarsGame.HEIGHT*/);
        mCamera.position.set(StarsGame.WIDTH_HALF, StarsGame.HEIGHT, 0);
        mViewport = new FitViewport(StarsGame.WIDTH, StarsGame.HEIGHT, mCamera);
        mCamera.position.set(mCamera.viewportWidth / 2f, mCamera.viewportHeight / 2 , 0);

        initStage();
        initInputMultiplexer();
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return mStage;
    }
    private void initStage() {
        mStage = new Stage(mViewport);
        mStage.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override public boolean keyUp(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
                if (keycode == Input.Keys.BACK)
                {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
                return super.keyUp(event, keycode);
            }
        });
    }
}
```